# ListView.builder() rebuilds widget on scrolling and the state of the widget is lost

Tags: android, flutter, dart, provider, flutter-listview

I am trying to make an application using Flutter and Provider for state management[image: application main screen]

I have used the ListView.builder() to generate a list of CabinWidget() widgets, each cabin widget is a Column of two Rows, each row having 4 containers, these containers are the SeatWidget(), these seat widgets are containers wrapped with GestureDetector, which changes state onTap, everythis is working fine, but when I scroll down past seat no. 48, so the state of the seats before that, say seat 5, is lost and is unchecked, but the data is still present in the shared data, in the Provider Class.

Any idea how to fix that??

**HomeScreen**

```
class SelectionButtonPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SelectionButtonPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SelectionButtonPage> createState() => _SelectionButtonPageState();
}

class _SelectionButtonPageState extends State<SelectionButtonPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    List<Seat> seats = Provider.of<SelectionButtonProvider>(context, listen: false).selectedSeats;

    for (var x in seats) {
      log("--------------------");
      log(x.seatIndex.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log("SelectionButtonPage built");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff126DCA),
        title: const Text("Select Your Seats"),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 8.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            Provider.of<SelectionButtonProvider>(context, listen: false).selectedSeats.forEach((element) {
              log(element.seatIndex.toString());
            });
          },
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff126DCA),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
          label: const Text("Confirm Selection"),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return CabinWidget(
              index: index,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Cabin Widget**

```
class CabinWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CabinWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.index,
  });

  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  children: [
                    ClipPath(
                      clipper: MyCustomCliperFromTop(),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 60,
                        width: 200,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                          color: const Color(0xff80CBFF),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SeatWidget(
                            seatIndex: 1 + index * 8,
                            seatType: "Upper",
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 4,
                          ),
                          SeatWidget(
                            seatIndex: 2 + index * 8,
                            seatType: "Middle",
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 4,
                          ),
                          SeatWidget(
                            seatIndex: 3 + index * 8,
                            seatType: "Lower",
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  children: [
                    ClipPath(
                      clipper: MyCustomCliperFromTop(),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 60,
                        width: 72,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                          color: const Color(0xff80CBFF),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      child: SeatWidget(
                        seatIndex: 7 + index * 8,
                        seatType: "Side Up",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 16,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  children: [
                    ClipPath(
                      clipper: MyCustomCliperFromBottom(),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 60,
                        width: 200,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                          color: const Color(0xff80CBFF),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SeatWidget(
                            seatIndex: 6 + index * 8,
                            seatType: "Upper",
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 4,
                          ),
                          SeatWidget(
                            seatIndex: 5 + index * 8,
                            seatType: "Middle",
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 4,
                          ),
                          SeatWidget(
                            seatIndex: 4 + index * 8,
                            seatType: "Lower",
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  children: [
                    ClipPath(
                      clipper: MyCustomCliperFromBottom(),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 60,
                        width: 72,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                          color: const Color(0xff80CBFF),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                      child: SeatWidget(
                        seatIndex: 8 + index * 8,
                        seatType: "Side Low",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 2),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Seat Widget**

```
class SeatWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SeatWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.seatIndex,
    required this.seatType,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int seatIndex;
  final String seatType;

  @override
  State<SeatWidget> createState() => _SeatWidgetState();
}

class _SeatWidgetState extends State<SeatWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Seat seat = Seat(seatIndex: widget.seatIndex, seatType: widget.seatType);
    log("SeatIndex: ${seat.seatIndex}");
    log("SeatType: ${seat.seatType}");
    return Consumer<SelectionButtonProvider>(
      builder: (context, selectionButtonProvider, child) {
        log("SeatWidget Rebuilt");
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            selectionButtonProvider.addSeat(seat);
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 60,
            width: 60,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              color: (selectionButtonProvider.isSeatSelected(seat)) ? const Color(0xff126DCA) : const Color(0xffCEEAFF),
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  widget.seatIndex.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: (selectionButtonProvider.isSeatSelected(seat)) ? const Color(0xffCEEAFF) : const Color(0xff126DCA),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 4),
                Text(
                  widget.seatType,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: (selectionButtonProvider.isSeatSelected(seat)) ? const Color(0xffCEEAFF) : const Color(0xff126DCA),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Seat Provider**

```
class SelectionButtonProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Seat> _selectedSeats = [];

  List<Seat> get selectedSeats => _selectedSeats;

  void addSeat(Seat seat) {
    log(seat.seatIndex.toString());

    if (_selectedSeats.contains(seat)) {
      _selectedSeats.remove(seat);
      log("${seat.seatIndex} removed");
      notifyListeners();
      return;
    }
    _selectedSeats.add(seat);
    log("${seat.seatIndex} added");
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool isSeatSelected(Seat seat) {
    bool result = _selectedSeats.contains(seat);
    log(result.toString());
    return _selectedSeats.contains(seat);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens because when your stateful widgets get scrolled out of view (with some additional space for caching), then their state objects will be disposed.

Either store all state outside of the list, or make use of the **KeepAlive** function inside of the **ListView**. Just remember that this will affect your performance for long lists with many children.

You can do that within your state class of the children of the list by implementing a mixin inside of your state subclass. Here is some example code:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) => _build(context)))));

Widget _build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 40,
    addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
    addRepaintBoundaries: true,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return const CustomKeepAliveWidget();
    },
  );
}

int counter = 0;

class _CustomKeepAliveWidgetState extends State<CustomKeepAliveWidget>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<CustomKeepAliveWidget> {
  bool _alive = true;
  late final String text;

  @override
  void initState() {
    text = "${counter++}";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return SizedBox(height: 100, child: Text("text: $text"));
  }

  void changeAlive() {
    // after this, it will no longer be kept alive!
    setState(() {
      _alive = !_alive;
      updateKeepAlive();
    });
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => _alive;
}

class CustomKeepAliveWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomKeepAliveWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomKeepAliveWidget> createState() => _CustomKeepAliveWidgetState();
}
```